# Is this a dialogue tag?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing, dialogue

Lately, I've been pondering about this question.

First of all, we already know that dialogue tags consist of a noun or a pronoun followed by a verb like "said," and "ask."

> "Like this one," I said.

Also, when using an action tag, the dialogue must have a full stop.

> "Like this?" I looked at the text above.

Would "is my only answer" be considered a dialogue tag with that structure? I can't really consider it one since it doesn't have the same structure.

> "I don't know," is my only answer.

Comment: Why have you switched from past to present tense? In a (highly-stylised) present tense narrative context you could reasonably use ***is***, but for the past tense context you've given here, it really needs to be *"I don't know," **was** my only answer*.

Comment: I would not use a comma in the last example. (So, I would not consider it a dialogue tag.) But it's more a matter of style than anything else.  Nor, for that matter, is there a dialague tag in your second example; it's simply two sentences.

Comment: FumbleFingers, Actually, the last sentence was something I found from a book. Jason Bassford, I had said "action tag," not dialogue tag. But I thank the two of you for commenting on this.